# unable to assign a value in ngFor loop: cannot assign to readonly property of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

temp.html code

```
<div>
<div>{{status}}</div>
</div>





 <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let d of list">
               <td>{{d.desc}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

d.desc has value :submitted,pending,partial
I want if d.desc is pending, status should change to pending.I don't want loop or filter in ts file
ts file has variable

```
public status:string="ok";
public list:any=[{"desc":"submitted"},{"desc":"pending"},{"desc":"partial"}]
```

I am trying but got cannot assign to readonly property of object

Comment: Can you add/show the ts file?

Comment: What is your `.ts`?

Comment: ts has variable public status:string="ok";
public list:any=['submitted','pending','partial']
i am taking data from api soo i can't share json etc

Comment: I am also trying {{updateStatus(d.desc)}} but getting same error,
updateStatus(desc:string){if(desc=='pending')this.status='pending'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve directly! But still you can use function and call that function from html by passing the status.
I have created a stackblitz for that! Take a look at it!
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7bxve

In html...

```
<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let d of list">
      <td>{{showStatus(d.desc)}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And in ts file...

```
showStatus(status) {
   this.status = status;
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy,problem was in my ts file status belong to interface ,when i change interface to class it worked